# How to make required = true in inputtext inside <p:dialog>

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

So, basically I just want to set inputTextArea validation is not null / required = true, but when I set that, it's effect other button too. So, i should set param and it won't effect other button.

But, it makes the validation isn't working. Here's my code  :

```
    <p:dialog id="ajaxdialogs" header="Hapus Data" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg1" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" closable="true"> 
    <p:messages id="errorx"></p:messages>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <p:outputLabel value="Anda yakin ingin menghapus #{empGradeBacking.selectedEmp.empGradeName}?"></p:outputLabel>
        <h:panelGrid styleClass="reasonDown">
            <p:outputLabel value="Alasan "></p:outputLabel> 
            <p:inputTextarea required="#{param['form:inputtext']==null} true" value="#{empGradeBacking.selectedEmp.deletedReason}" cols="40" rows="5" minQueryLength="1" counter="display" maxlength="200" autoResize="false"  counterTemplate="{0} karakter tersisa" validatorMessage="alasan tidak boleh kosong"></p:inputTextarea>
            <h:outputText id="display" styleClass="charremaining"></h:outputText>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid styleClass="addDeleteDown" columns="2">
        <p:commandButton id="inputtext" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" value="#{UIBundle['text.page.button.yes']}" actionListener="#{empGradeBacking.deleteEmpGrade}" icon="ui-icon-check" oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('dlg1').hide()" update="errorx @([id$=empB])"></p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="#{UIBundle['text.page.button.no']}" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').hide()" icon="ui-icon-close" immediate="true"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: INstead using required why not using a simple verification from the managedBean

Comment: `p:commandButton` `process` attribute defaults to `@form` and since your dialog is in the same form, that's why your validation "isn't working" outside of the dialog. Either put your dialog in its own form or specify only the components you need to `process` by doing `process="id1 id2..."`. Let me know if that didn't make sense but I think that is your problem.